# Laravel create a route with slug and id

Tags: php, laravel

At this time i have

```
Route::get('properties/{id}', 'InfoController@show');
```

And the link looks like `mydoamin.com/properties/1`

Is there any posibility to create a route to have `properties/id/slug(from title)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by doing the following:

Update your route:

```
Route::get('properties/{id}/{slug}', 'InfoController@show');
```

Then accept the route in your controller and check there is a valid model with the given `id` and `slug`.

```
public function show($id, $slug) {
    $model = Model::where('id', $id)
                  ->where('slug', $slug)
                  ->first();

    if(! $model) {
        // handle error here
    }

    return view('show', compact('model'));
}
```

(Note that validation can also be done by creating a custom Form Request: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do like this,

`Route::get('properties/{id}/{title}', 'InfoController@show');`

on show function

`public function show ($id, $title) {`

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the route to `Route::get('properties/{id}/{slug}', 'InfoController@show');`

The check if the slug can be matched with the title have to placed in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ModelController (with a slug field and regular CRUD show function)

```
public function slug($slug) { return $this->show(Model::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail()); }
```

Add this route to web.php (to match all non-all-numeric slugs not containing '/'

```
Route::get ('model/{slug}', 'ModelController@slug')->where(['slug' => '^(?!((.*/)|(create$))).*\D+.*$']);
```

Make sure it comes before

```
Route::resource('model', 'ModelController');
```

You'll match any non-all-numeric slugs, but pass through integers to the regular route.